# custom notifyicon register User32.TrackMouseEvent mouseleave event invalid

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, visual-c++

- I created a custom NotifyIcon through the Windows API.
- I call OnMouseEnter when MouseMove is triggered in the callback function for the custom notification icon.
- I registered the MouseLeave event in OnMouseEnter, and it didn't work.

Remark:

- I registered the Mouseleave event in a normal window, and it worked fine.

C# WPF Code

```
    private IntPtr CallBack(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
    {
        if (IsLoaded)
        {
            var wm = lparam.ToInt32();
            switch (wm)
            {
                case WM.LBUTTONDBLCLK:
                    OnMouseDoubleClick();
                    break;
                case WM.LBUTTONDOWN:
                    OnMouseDown(MouseButton.Left);
                    break;
                case WM.LBUTTONUP:
                    OnMouseUp(MouseButton.Left);
                    break;
                case WM.RBUTTONDOWN:
                    OnMouseDown(MouseButton.Right);
                    break;
                case WM.RBUTTONUP:
                    OnMouseUp(MouseButton.Right);
                    break;
                case WM.MOUSEMOVE:
                    OnMouseMove();
                    OnMouseEnter();
                    break;
                case WM.MOUSELEAVE:
                    // not working
                    OnMouseLeave();
                    break;
                case WM.MOUSEHOVER:
                case WM.NCMOUSEHOVER:
                case WM.NCMOUSELEAVE:
                    // not working
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine(wm);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return User32.DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
    }

    private void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        if (!mouseEnter)
        {
            mouseEnter = true;
            var dwFlags = TME.LEAVE | TME.HOVER;
            var lpEventTrack = new TRACKMOUSEEVENT()
            {
                cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT)),
                dwFlags =(int)dwFlags,
                hwndTrack = hNotifyIcon
            };
            var result = User32.TrackMouseEvent(ref lpEventTrack);
            if (!result)
            {
                Kernel32.ThowError();
            }
            RaiseEvent(new MouseEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, Environment.TickCount)
            {
                RoutedEvent = MouseEnterEvent,
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you using all those events for?  I have used NotifyIcons in several WinForms apps, and the out of the box control (which provides for Click, DblClick, MouseClick (more event args), MouseDblClick, MouseDown, MouseUp and MouseMove and some events related to the "balloon") has served me fine.  I'm guessing there's a similar control in WPF-land

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot treat NotifyIcon as a window. I don’t know how you get the `hNotifyIcon`, but you can’t get `WM_MOUSELEAVE` event directly on NotifyIcon.

You will need to hook all `WM_MOUSEMOVE` event with [mouse hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) or [Raw Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/raw-input) when NotifyIcon starts sending `WM_MOUSEMOVE` notification to the associated window.

In addition, the process of handling the notification of NotifyIcon needs to be improved. The notification should only be processed when `msg` = [`NOTIFYICONDATA.uCallbackMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataa?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Then get the RECT area of NotifyIcon through [`Shell_NotifyIconGetRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyicongetrect), and judge whether the coordinates obtained in the hook callback are in this RECT([`PtInRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-ptinrect)), if not, the mouse leaves NotifyIcon, unregister the hook.

Comment: 兄弟，非常感谢你的回答。我通过 [User32.GetCursorPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorpos) + [Shell32.Shell_NotifyIconGetRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyicongetrect) 解决了鼠标离开NotifyIcon

Comment: Glad you solved the problem, if this answer dose help you, you could feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer or add your own answer.